# Adding a value to a defined list in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

The thing i'm triying to do is the following:

I have to create a function that adds a value to a dictionary in scheme
so i defined the dictionary as a list of lists as it follows:

```
(define Dictionary '(("key 1" "value 1") ("key 2" "value")))
```

Now for the function that adds the values:

First of all i check if the element is not null and that the element has a key and value before trying to add it to the list

```
(define (addElement element mylist)
    (cond 
        ((null? elemment) 'The_Element_Is_Null)
        ((null? (cdr element)) 'The_Element_is_singleTon)
        (#t (cons element mylist))
    )
)
```

And try to run it as it follows:

```
(addElement '("key 3" "value 3") Dictionary)
```

and DrRacket executes the code it prints the following

```
(("key 3" "value 3") ("key 1" "value 1") ("key 2" "value"))
```

Note that using cons the value is displayed as if it was added to the list but the value is not, similar to other languajes where is possible to print something similar to this

```
int i = 1;
print("value = "+ i + 5);
```

the program should print

```
value = 6
```

but in reality the value of the variable is 1, in the same way, my dictionary is not getting new values and executing this code just prints the list with the new element but the element is not really added to the list

One solution i tried is using the method set! to try adding the value but i'm getting the same result

```
(define (addElement element mylist)
    (cond 
        ((null? elemment) 'The_Element_Is_Null)
        ((null? (cdr element)) 'The_Element_is_singleTon)
        (#t (set! myList(cons element mylist)))
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this function is supposed to modify a dictionary? It's much more common to have a function that returns a new dictionary that is like the old one but with the item added. (Used like `(define new-dict (add-element '("this" "that") old-dict))`.)

Comment: That was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scheme, most of the list operations that "modify" a list (for example: `cons`) do *not* actually update the input list, instead they create a new list, and you're supposed to store it or pass it along.

If you want a list modification made inside a procedure to be preserved once the procedure exits, you have to explicitly `set!` the modified list - your second attempt aims in the right direction but you're just setting a procedure's parameter, not the original list. I propose two alternatives:

```
; declare the list outside the procedure

(define Dictionary '())

; 1) either set! the list inside the procedure

(define (addElement element)
  (cond 
    ((null? element) 'The_Element_Is_Null)
    ((null? (cdr element)) 'The_Element_Is_Singleton)
    (else (set! Dictionary (cons element Dictionary)))))

(addElement '("key 1" "value 1"))

; 2) or set! the list with the result of calling the procedure

(define (addElement element myList)
  (cond 
    ((null? element) 'The_Element_Is_Null)
    ((null? (cdr element)) 'The_Element_Is_Singleton)
    (else (cons element myList))))

(set! Dictionary (addElement '("key 1" "value 1") Dictionary))
```

Be aware that in general this style of procedural programming using `set!` is *heavily discouraged* - what you want to do is pass the result of a procedure call that modifies a list to another procedure (function composition) or to the same procedure (as part of a recursion) and let it process the new result. Remember that Scheme is a functional programming language at its core, and things are done in a different way from what you're used to.

Comment: @D.Shinoda Did this answer your question? if so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, simply click on the check mark to its left ;)

Comment: Hey, just found out a different way that eliminates the need of set!, using (define ()) to redefine the list with the output of my function was what the assigment was about, but thanks anyway